# call action with parametr from route

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, zend-framework2

i have the following action in my zf2 controller

```
    public function indexAction($text1,$text2) {
}
```

is there any way to call indexAction with $text1 & $text2 params from route

for example :

> localhost/project/index/text1/sadasd/text2/asdasd

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Params`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin/Params.php).

Example code would be:

```
$t1 = $this->params()->fromRoute('text1');
$t2 = $this->params()->fromRoute('text1');

// Edit, actually fromRoute() is the default, so you can do it just like this
$t1 = $this->params('text1', $defaultValue);
```

Adding them as parameters to the `indexAction()` won't really do anything.